# How to use a while loop to read text consecutively from text file and output text parameters into a command

Tags: bash, loops, sed, while-loop, grep

We are trying to make a report that reads a `hosts.txt` file and an `infile`. It should make a header when it finds the first `host1` above the line containing the text `host1` and then put a new line under the header line it just created leaving all other text intact and keep doing it for hosts1-30.

Currently we do this with single `grep` and `sed` commands in functions. We add some header text above the first match, then we add a single blank line under that header text. In the example we show only 2 hosts `host1`, `host2`.

We are looking for a way to do this with a while loop instead of the single `sed/grep` commands. The hosts appear sequentially as they are found in the `infile` so this could be read sequentially from the `hosts.txt` in a while loop.

Here is the example of doing it manually with `sed` and `grep` commands. We have a single input file `infile`. The `grep/sed` statements matches the `host1` and `host2` and inputs a header above and a blank line below.

infile file: all text is literal - the random text is completely random.
There is never a [ ] except on the line where host1-30 is found:

```
1    any-random-text1 [host1][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2    any-old-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
1    some-random-text1 [host2][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2    any-stupid-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
```

Here is our `hosts.txt` file:

```
hosts.txt file:

host1
host2
```

We add a header now with our manual `sed` and `grep` - current working method:

```
header="Some Header Text We Need"

header() # I use a function in the example but it can be done without.
{
a=$(grep -n host1 outfile | cut -d : -f 1)
sed $a'i\'"**host1_ - ""$header"'\' outfile > outfile1
b=$(grep -n host2 outfile1 | cut -d : -f 1)
sed $b'i\'"**host2_ - ""$header"'\' outfile1 > outfile2
# we need to add a blank line now
a=$(grep -n -w host1 outfile2 | cut -d : -f 1)
sed $a'i\\' outfile2 > outfile3
b=$(grep -n -w host2 outfile3 | cut -d : -f 1)
sed $b'i\\' outfile3 > outfile4
}
```

Our output file `outfile4` is exactly what we need and this method works but we want to use a while loop instead that reads `hosts.txt` to find the `host1` and `host2` string that the grep command used above. Contents of outfile4:

```
 user@host$ cat outfile4
**host1_ - Some Header Text We Need

1   any-random-text1 [host1][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-old-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
**host2_ - Some Header Text We Need

1   some-random-text1 [host2][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-stupid-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
```

Instead - we would like to be able to do this with a while loop.: I tried this but it does not work.

```
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
hosts=hosts.txt
header="Some Header Text We Need"

addheader()
{
 while read -r LINE; do
   x=$(grep -n "$LINE" outfile | cut -d : -f 1)
   sed $x'i\'""$LINE_"' - ""$header"'\'
 done < hosts.txt > 2
}

addblankline()
{
 while read -r LINE; do
   a=$(grep -n -w $LINE outfile | cut -d : -f 1)
   sed $a'i\\'
 done < hosts.txt > 2
}
```

We would want our while loop to read `hosts.txt` and to look like how the `output4` file looks: with what our single manual `sed` & `grep` commands did for us:

```
 infile: this should look like outfile4 below:

1   any-random-text1 [host1][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-old-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
1   some-random-text1 [host2][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-stupid-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz


 outfile:
user@host$ cat outfile4
**host1_ - Some Header Text We Need

1   any-random-text1 [host1][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-old-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
**host2_ - Some Header Text We Need

1   some-random-text1 [host2][randomo randomp randomr randomc randomu]
2   any-stupid-random-text2 randome randomiest randomer randomo randomy randomx randomk randoml randomz
```

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what you are wanting if you did something like:

I have input files that look this: ...

I want output that looks like this: ...

Comment: I tried to - I made my example as small as I could. I want outfile4 to look like outfile4 but with a while loop instead of doing it with manual sed commands. outfile4 came from the outfile example file in the beginning - I want the while loop to make the output4 text like the sed commands did in my example.

Comment: My input file is `outfile` my output file is `outfile4`. I showed my working example with manual sed/grep commands. I showed how it does not work with my while loop. I want the while loop to create `outfile4` exactly how it shows it.

Comment: OK, as I dug into it more I figured out what you were asking... One more question. How do you tell if a line is "some-random-text" or "string2 random-text2"?  Is "some-random-text" all one word and the "string2" lines two words?

Comment: And can you figure out "string2" from "string1", or "random-text1" from "random-text2"?

Comment: random-text is not important - only host1 and host2 text is needed to be found in the file. Once host1 is found, the sed statement places the header above it. Once host2 is found the sed statement places the header above it. Then the second sed statement goes along and places a blank line under that the header for host1 then the header for host2.

Comment: the hosts file is important since it has exact same text - eg host1 host2 that the outfile has in it - host1 and host2 for where the header is placed and then the subsequent blank line under that header.

Comment: But "outfile4" has "random-text2" in it. How did you know how to include "random-text2"?

Comment: the file is literal - line 1 is a digit - the file is numbered. Line 2 is some-random-text - line 3 is host1 for eg - but that's not all that important since the grep statement only needs to find host1 and host2 to allow the sed statement to place its header and then its subsequent blank line under that header. The headers have to be placed and finished and then the blank line has to be done because sed uses line numbers to place its lines and it changes the amount of lines in the file where it finds host1 and host2 when adding the header.

Comment: Ok I am trying to figure that out. I think I might have hosed somemthing up in the example.

Comment: Ok random text is just there because it came from outfile. I would have to post the procedure to explain how I got the outfile.

Comment: I have a for hosts in cat host-date - for loop that does a grep/awk statement searchinfg for string1 and string2 and some-random-text happesn to be in front of string 2. This shouldnt change that we just need to place a header above host1/host2 and then after that put a blank line under the header we made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat /tmp/x.sh
#!/bin/sh

input="/tmp/infile.txt"
output="/tmp/outfile4.txt"
hosts="/tmp/hosts.txt"

header="blah blah blah"

for host in $(cat "${hosts}")
do
  echo "**${host}_ - ${header}"
  echo ""
  awk '/\[.*\]$/{n=0}(/\['${host}'\]$/||n){n++}n' "${input}" | sed 's/^/    /'    
done > "${outfile}"
```

input files:

```
$ cat /tmp/infile.txt 
 1   any-random-text1 [host1]
 2   any-old-random-text2
 1   some-random-text1 [host2]
 2   any-stupid-random-text2
$ cat /tmp/hosts.txt 
host1
host2
```

output:

```
$ /tmp/x.sh
$ cat /tmp/outfile4.txt
**host1_ - blah blah blah

     1   any-random-text1 [host1]
     2   any-old-random-text2
**host2_ - blah blah blah

     1   some-random-text1 [host2]
     2   any-stupid-random-text2
```

The awk statement relies on there not being any match of [.*]$ in "any-*-random-text. If it's possible that this will be in your infile then a more explicit pattern match is needed.

Comment: As near as i can tell this does what you've asked for.

Comment: This appears to do the trick but the issue is that it is looking for random-text.. random-text is irrelevant in the example - the only thing I have to work with is searching for the host1 and host2

Comment: it appears to work for adding the header and the blank line but it is removing lines from the file - it removes the line2 and line 4

Comment: I did modify my outfile above since It was not very clear. I should call outfile=infile and outfile4=outfile. Anyway -  I will try to work with your example since it is very close to what I am trying to do just need to modify it to not remove any lines from the file.

Comment: i should say that from when it finds the host1 - there is several hundred lines of important data that is under that which is for the report - so the header is made for host1 & the blank line under that header.... Then it finds host2 and then there is several hundred lines of data that is for the host2 ect and on and on for 30 hosts.

Comment: It would have been easier to have just posted "I have this..." and "I want this...  How?" See latest.

Comment: hmm - this works in the example but it deletes every line in production except the header line and the blank line it has added. I will try to figure out the difference.

Comment: I see what has happened - as soon as I add any text further than 2 columns over it deletes every other line from the file. The real file has 7-10 columns. So if I add any-old-random-text2 extra-columns more-text more-text it deletes every line except the header & blank line it adds.

Comment: play with the regex. i'm guessing your input file doesn't look like '[hostN]'

Comment: The input file has exactly [hostn] i mean within reason it's not the exact word 'host'.

Comment: As mentioned twice before, it'd be much easier to resolve this with example input. There's important parts being left out of your examples. Until then you need to figure out a regex that works on your input file. The solution provided works on what you have posted.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks - I will look into a string that does what I need.

Comment: The `"$"` in the regex matches "end of line" so the extra text after `...[hostN][rand rand rand]` is what's causing it not to work. If `'[hostN]'` is guaranteed to never be in `'[rand...]'`  and the intermediate 'any-old-text' lines then just take out the `"$"`.  If your input is just like you've shown then `'/\['${host}'\]\[.*\]$/'` would work.

Comment: The only one that puts the headers in the right place is the very first one you posted. The other one does all kind of funky stuff like some have 1-2 lines when it should have hundreds and it duplicates stuff. I think its matching extra [rand-rand] past the match with [hostN] which there is alot of [rand-rand]'s - every other line in the whole file. I just need to learn regex and awk. Thanks for the input.